# Unable to ssh into machine, get 'The system is going down for reboot in 4 minutes!'

Tags: ssh, reboot

I am trying to ssh into a machine and after I enter the password I get this:

> ```
> The system is going down for reboot in 4 minutes!
> Authentication failed.
> ```

Does anyone know what is going on or have any suggestions?

This machine is on the other side of the world so I don't have physical access to it. I cut the power to it using a web power switch to force it to restart but once it started back up I still got the same error.

Comment: It has been four minutes.  Has the message changed?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you wait 4 mins and check it? If your box is on the other side of the planet, I would expect you to have some kind of Lights Out Management. Can you connect to that and drop to a console?

Comment: I waited 4 minutes (and longer) and the message never changed. I'm not really familiar with lights out management but a quick google search leads me to believe that we don't have anything like that. This isn't the most advanced system, its used to operate some research equipment and I didn't have a part in setting it up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard message when the "I'm going to restart" flag is set. This is typically either the file `/etc/nologin` or `/var/run/nologin`. It's checked by the PAM module `pam_nologin` (see `man pam_nologin` for details).

Even though normal logins are blocked you should still be able to log in as root, at which point you can remove the flag file, or run `shutdown -c` to cancel a real scheduled shutdown.